# Resource URL is incorrect

Tags: wordpress, resource-urls

Wordpress 5.0 Civi 5.14

***UPDATE***
I am now convinced that the resource URL error is a real issue and not just a false positive.  I just tried to add some component to the CKeditor.  I saved it, I cleaned up the cache. The new components are not showing up on the ckeditor in the contribution pages.  This is not an issue on my other clients civi installs, just this one.

Hello,
I just finished a fresh install of Civi on a new site for a client.
I am getting the Alert that the Resource URL is incorrect.  As far as I can tell, it is correct.

Also the contribution page url is showing incorrectly in the configurations. It is showing as: subdomain.mysite.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=1

It should be: subdomain.mysite.org/**civicrm**?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=1

I think that might be a clue to the resource url problem, but I have been digging for hours and I can't find where to fix it.

See screenshots below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

****UPDATE TO SHOW civicrm.settings.php *****
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alert is incorrect.  As long as you are not having any other issues besides the alert, you can tell the alert not to remind you again.

In addition (now that I see the issue with Contribution pages - sorry I missed that), make sure you have the base page set under CMS settings in the CiviCRM administration settings.

[image]

In WP go to settings, Permalinks. Make sure that they are not set to Plain

[image]

Lastly make sure the base page is published.  the page '/civicrm' is added on install
[image]

Comment: Except they are having issues with the contribute page. And civicrm_root seems to work on wpmaster?

Comment: @KevinCristiano Thank you. I have installed Civi many times, and this alert not going away is a first for me, but I am seeing other posts about it being a false positive.  However, I am still have the issue with the configuration page URL and I believe that might be related to resource URL issue.  See the third screenshot. I hope that gives a clue to what path is not correct and where it is.    it might help to point out that this subdomain didn't install in the public_html folder like I think it usually does. It installed outside that folder. Only the root domain has the public_html folder.

Comment: Demerit, I will look at wpmaster, I know that is a buildkit install and that does many things different than a manual install

Comment: Thank you.  Setting the WP Integration solved the problem with the contribution page URLs.  The Incorrect Resource URL is still coming up and now it also say Cron is not running.  But this solved the first part of the problem.  I ll have to start another thread about Cron.

Comment: Thanks also @KevinCristiano. Note the cron will always warn if it hasn't run in the last hour (https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.14/CRM/Utils/Check/Component/Env.php#L296)

Comment: It says  Last cron run at June 29th, 2019 3:46 PM.   That was yesterday afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it's `[civicrm.root]/`.
Is that screenshot just an example of values you've been playing with? Does it work with `[civicrm.root]/`?

And `[civicrm.root]/` is what it is set to on https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org.

Also check your civicrm.settings.php file to see if it's overriding it for some reason.

Comment: Those are the values I am working with. It displayed that way after the install and that particular textarea is READ ONLY, so I can't change it to [civicrm.root]/.  I just added another screenshot to show what my civicrm.settings.php file looks like.  It appears to match what  on the resource urls page.  I would try adding [civicrm.root]/ there if it wasn't read only.

Comment: Ok, thanks. If you comment out or remove the line in civicrm.settings.php and then put [civicrm.root]/ in the field does that help?

Comment: I just tried.  There was not a change

Comment: @Demerit in WP installs in oder to handle the multiple installation configurations we do not use `[cicicrm_root]` and put the proper paths in the `civicrm.settings.php` file.  The alert is wrong.  It has been for as long as it has been part of core and I disable on all WP sites.  I have yet to find one where it works.

Comment: @KevinCristiano I am wondering how to disable that alert.  I decided it must be a false positive too.   Do you have instructions on that?

Comment: Go to administer - administration console - system status and you'll see a hide button beside the warning.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem on a Drupal installation and found a cause. In my situation, it was a false positive.

To check if the resource URL is correctly set CiviCRM tries to download the following picture from the server

`https://<server>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png`

It does the check, however, on the server itself, and that was protected by an IP firewall, that prevented browsing from the server. If you have SSH access you can check it with the following command:

`curl https://<server>/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/jquery/css/images/arrow.png`

Answer (score 0):

I am on wp and the error I have (which is just a notice)  is make the resource urls are portable. That's the false positive. 
I don't think the incorrect resource url error that you have is a false positive seems to be something wrong.